# Extract array dimensions in Julia

Tags: arrays, matlab, julia

Given a vector A defined in Matlab by:

```
A =  [ 0
       0
       1
       0
       0 ];
```

we can extract its dimensions using:

```
size(A);
```

Apparently, we can achieve the same things in Julia using:

```
 size(A)
```

Just that in Matlab we are able to extract the dimensions in a vector, by using:

```
[n, m] = size(A);
```

irrespective to the fact whether A is one or two-dimensional, while in Julia A, size (A) will return only one dimension if A has only one dimension.

How can I do the same thing as in Matlab in Julia, namely, extracting the dimension of A, if A is a vector, in a vector [n m]. Please, take into account that the dimensions of A might vary, i.e. it could have sometimes 1 and sometimes 2 dimensions.

Comment: What would you expect ``m`` to be after the assignment, when the size is to small?

Comment: I am not sure I understood your question. The size of A will vary with respect to both n and m. I am interested to take m and n to pass them of a function. m would take values between 1 and 3. It's a small model we are talking about.

Comment: I am completely new to Julia. I may throw a different look at this issue: can I force a vector of dimensions (n,1) to be a matrix of dimensions (n,1)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
A = zeros(3,5)
sz = size(A)
```

returns a tuple `(3,5)`. You can refer to specific elements like `sz[1]`. Alternatively,

```
m,n = size(A,1), size(A,2)
```

This works even if `A` is a column vector (i.e., one-dimensional), returning a value of `1` for  `n`.

Comment: What about `A = zeros(3,5,2); [n, m] = size(A);`? In MATLAB I'd get n = 3 and m = 10. How can I achieve something similar in Julia?

Answer (score 6):

This will achieve what you're expecting:

```
n, m = size(A); #or 
(n, m) = size(A);
```

If `size(A)` is a one dimensional `Tuple`, `m` will not be assigned, while `n` will receive `length(A)`. Just be sure to catch that error, otherwise your code may stop if running from a script.